# Crystal Report TextBox

Tags: crystal-reports

I am working on crystal report, i need to pass value(from Winforms) to crystal report 
Textbox control's like `Period:10-11-2009 To 13-11-20009` this value I want pass for crystal report textbox control

advance wishes...

Comment: I had the same problem and here is the answer: [Passing parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35862733/crystal-report-invalid-index-exception-from-hresult-0x8002000b-disp-e-badin/35954722#35954722)

Answer (score 2):

see this link it shows how to pass parametar to crystal report.There are many more examples for this just ask google

[link to an example](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/paramInCR11012006132839PM/paramInCR.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass values to crystal using parameters. Then you can display these in the reports.

Answer (score 1):

```
 See the code below

 //Initialize your report
 sample_report yourReport = new sample_report();

 CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.TextObject variableName=
 (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.TextObject)
 yourReport.Section2.ReportObjects["nameoftheTextboxInyourReport"];

 variableName.Text = "Period:10-11-2009 To 13-11-20009";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the from date and to date in the details or header column that you are passing through the data source to the crystal report .. drag those fields from the field explorer and put them into the text field

Answer (score 0):

Just use parameters and pass the Textbox value :

Example in VB.NET :

```
Dim rptList As ReportDocument = New ReportDocument()
With rptList
    .Load(strPath)
    .SetDataSource(dtsData)
    rptList.SetParameterValue("SomeName", yourTextBox.Text.trim)
End With
```

strPath is the path to your .rpt file and dtsData is the dataset.

in SetParameterValue define a name and value, just notice that you should create a parameter with the same name in your crystal report.

Answer (score 0):

```
' txtName = textbox name in crystal report
' txtValue = text value to be passed to report

    Dim objText As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.TextObject =RtpDocument.ReportDefinition.Sections(1).ReportObjects(txtName)

    objText.Text = txtValue
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = RtpDocument
```