# Crystal Report: Invalid index. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002000B (DISP_E_BADINDEX))

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, crystal-reports

I can not pass values to the report.

This is my code:

```
public void GLRPT()
        {
            try
            {

                ReportClass rptH = new ReportClass();
                rptH.FileName = Server.MapPath("~/Rpts/G1.rpt");
                rptH.Load();

                string df = Session["fromdate"].ToString();
                string dt = Session["todate"].ToString();
                DateTime fromdate = DateTime.Parse(df);
                DateTime todate = DateTime.Parse(dt);

                rptH.SetParameterValue("?Date_From", fromdate);
                rptH.SetParameterValue("?Date_To", todate);
                rptH.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response, false, "GL");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

I don't know why I see this error:

**Invalid index. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002000B (DISP_E_BADINDEX))**

Comment: Probably because parameters ?Date_From and Date_To dont exist in your report, or have been spelled incorrectly.

Comment: But it exists with this name. and that is my problem.
I tried **Date_From** and **@Date_From** and **?Date_From** but none of them works.

Comment: at which point/line do you get the error?

Comment: rptH.SetParameterValue("?Date_From", fromdate);

Comment: Does the report have same type of paramter i.e. date?

Comment: Yes the report have same type of parameter

Comment: Does the database fields and the reports database source fields match? If there is any missing field,, this error would appear

Comment: Yes everything matches with each other

Comment: But I found the solution. I should write like this **rptH.SetParameterValue("Date_From", fromdate);** then I should give database access to the report. I write my answer.

Comment: Just look at the answer.

Comment: Good job... you finally did it yourself..

Comment: Thanks! Can you please add +1 point to this page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We should pass the parameter value like this:

```
rptH.SetParameterValue("Date_From", fromdate); //correct
```

**NOT**

```
rptH.SetParameterValue("?Date_From", fromdate); //incorrect
```

Then we we must give **database access** to the report because without login to database the report will not be opened.
and here is the code:

```
ReportDocument rptH = new ReportDocument();
TableLogOnInfos crtableLogoninfos = new TableLogOnInfos();
TableLogOnInfo crtableLogoninfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
ConnectionInfo crConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
Tables CrTables;

rptH.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Rpts/G1.rpt"));

string df = Session["fromdate"].ToString();
string dt = Session["todate"].ToString();
DateTime fromdate = DateTime.Parse(df);
DateTime todate = DateTime.Parse(dt);

rptH.SetParameterValue("Date_From", fromdate);
rptH.SetParameterValue("Date_To", todate);

crConnectionInfo.ServerName = "YOUR SERVER NAME";
crConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "YOUR DATABASE NAME";
crConnectionInfo.UserID = "YOUR DATABASE USERNAME";
crConnectionInfo.Password = "YOUR DATABASE PASSWORD";

CrTables = rptH.Database.Tables;
foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table CrTable in CrTables)
{
    crtableLogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo;
    crtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo;
    CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo);
}

rptH.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response, false, "GL");
```

> We must call **the parameter's name without any additional character** such as
>   **@** or **?**, just only the parameter's name itself.

Comment: With .NET 4.6.1 and Crystal Reports 11.5, I had to use **@** with parameter name. Without **@** symbol it is assuming parameter name as index.

Answer (score 0):

I know the topic a little bit old, but it might help for someone if I share my experience.

As we can read in many topics, "the parameters name are different in the report file and the code". Yes this is true, but it is also happens if you added or removed parameters from the report file and forgot to copy the new file into your application location.
It would be the Visual Studio job, but sometimes the VS forget to copy the modified report file to the "Debug" folder, I think.

The point of this writing, after you modified your report file, regarding parameters, copy it into your compiled location.